# Where can I find a Silverlight HTML editor with WYSIWYG?

Tags: html, silverlight, ide, wysiwyg

We have a CMS system that we're currently taking the admin back end and converting to Silverlight 3 or possibly 4 by the time we go to production. We wrote a custom JS / DHTML editor to suit our needs, and will need to do the same now in Silverlight.  Has anyone seen any clues to a base functionality that we could build upon for our own app?

We don't really have the time to build from scratch, but it's looking as if this might be our only solution for today. Any help would be greatly appreciated. http://www.vectorlight.net/controls/rich_textbox.aspx  We came across this control, but there’s no option to buy the source code.  Something similar could be enough for now, as long as we could modify it to our needs.  Price is not a huge issue, as long as it was less than $2K. That’s the tipping point where I’d need to make a real business case for it outside our team.

Comment: "no option to buy the source code", have you actually asked them?

Comment: I sent an email to their support address about a week ago. Either it was ignored, they're not actively checking their email, or it got caught in a spam filter being a public email server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I work for a company that has just released a Silverlight Control suite and one of the controsl we have developed is a Silverlight HTML Editor.

[Silverlight Html Editor](http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/silverlightelements/controls/silverlight-html-editor)

It includes basic functionality and we're growing the capabilities based on customer demand. It allows HTML import and export which I think is your key initial requirement.

Source code is available for purchase if desired and the price is well down on the $2000 upper limit that you have :-)

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the Rich Notepad Silverlight 4 sample from Microsoft?
http://silverlight.net/community/samples/silverlight-4-beta/rich-notepad/

Comment: I haven't seen that.  The critical point would be an HTML export that would be dumped into our SQL database and off hand this looks like it's in a proprietary format.  I'll dig deeper though - hopefully this could be a stepping stone to something that could work.

Comment: The link doesn't appear to still be working...are you able to update it?

Comment: It is not on the site anymore - guess MS have removed many of the beta 4 samples.

Answer (score 0):

The `XamRichTextEditor` is a highly customizable rich text editing control that provides functionality modeled after the features and behavior of Microsoft Word. The `XamRichTextEditor` is provided in both WPF and Silverlight versions with an API that is common across both platforms, enabling you to incorporate rich text editing capabilities into your cross platform applications.

http://www.infragistics.com/products/silverlight/editors/rich-text-editor

Answer (score -1):

We're going to give the component art component a shot. http://www.componentart.com/products/silverlight/editors/

I chatted with their support a bit, and the toolbar is separate from the editor, and highly customizable with our own features. I'll try to remember to post back some feedback if it's good, so that others can benefit.